# Accessing form_for object's attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, cocoon-gem

Accessing one of the variables in form_for gives me the error:

> undefined local variable or method `goal'

Partial code is as follows:

```
  <%= f.fields_for :goals do |builder| %>
      <%= render 'goal_fields_public', :f => builder %>
  <% end %>
```

The form code is as follows:

```
= f.fields_for :goals do |goal|
  = render 'goal_fields', f: goal
```

When using debug tag, I can see @object with my goal's sublfield in it.
Population of the form is happening as expected. I was expecting to get `goal.objects.name_of_subobject` working ok, but for some reason it does not.

Comment: Would you add the code for your 'goal_fields' partial?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the code you're showing, and nothing that would generate that error. Look at the error and see the file and line that it's coming from, and add that code to your question.

Comment: updated with partial code

Comment: Ok. Thanks. What is in your 'goal_fields_public' partial or wherever you make the call to `goal.object.name_of_subobject`...

Comment: Your form code and partial seem identical (although one is erb and the other is haml). Either a goal can have many goals again, and in that case please show us the next partial `goal_fields_public`, or post the correct `goal_fields` partial. For now I still see no reference to a `goal.object` begin made. Could you also show us the line where the error occurred?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fields_for` will iterate over a collection, so in each instance of `goal_fields` you will have a `goal` form builder, for which you can access a single object, not a collection.

`goal.object.name_of_subobject`

Edit: after partial has been posted it appears that you've duplicated your `fields_for` tag, resulting in code like so:

```
f.fields_for :goals do |builder| %>
  builder.fields_for :goals do |goal|
    render 'goal_fields', f: goal
```

And do you have a `form_for` tag anywhere in here? Either you've not posted half the context we need to help you with this, or your form has a lot of problems.

(You're also mixing haml and erb, why?)

Comment: yeah, my logic exactly. problem is, it's undefined

Comment: @kaboom Your post states `objects` not `object` - are you certain?

Comment: double checked, object it is, in singular

Comment: It is a nested attribute, there is a for_for higher up indeed

Comment: <%= form_for(@set_of_goals) do |f| %>

Comment: @kaboom Can you see though how you have `fields for goals` immediately followed by `fields for goals`? Unless your goals each have a collection of goals, your partial does not need a `fields_for` tag, just the fields themselves.

Answer (score 0):

Your 'goal_fields' partial might be referencing the local variable `goal` not `f`. If so, you can change your call to render as follows:

```
= render 'goal_fields', goal: goal
```